# Automatically Disallow File Editing when WordPress is installed

Tags: php, wordpress, automation

We have a WordPress base starter theme on which we build multiple sites. This repo includes the theme as well as all the WP core files (pre-WP-installation) to make setup as quick as possible. For security reasons I want to disable file editing from the WordPress dashboard. https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress

This can be done by adding the following snippet to wp-config.php

`## Disable Editing in Dashboard
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);`

#### Here is my question:

is there a way to edit the `sample-wp-config.php` so that it will always include the snippet above when I run a WordPress installation and creates the `wp-config.php` for that project. The goal that is I don't need to add the snippet every time I start a new project off our base repo.

Comment: There are tools like [WP Quick Install](https://github.com/GeekPress/WP-Quick-Install) ( [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/toolbox-of-the-smart-wordpress-developer-wp-quick-install--cms-23832) ) that lets you automate the instalation process, including the some tweaks in the `wp-config.php` file.

Comment: That is very helpful, might be the only answer shy of creating my own custom plugin or script.